# Не пойму где ошибка в связях таблиц БД

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, sequelize.js

Всем доброго дня! при добавлении дополнительной таблицы в проект и настройки ассоциаций, при запуске сервера не запускается mixin, ругаясь на связи. В аналогичном другом проекте все работало, здесь не хочет. помогите разобраться плиз. Делал перенакатку базы, но не помогает. прикладываю код и описание ошибки. возможно я чего - то не вижу или не понимаю, что требуется:

```
        
    /home/ds/elbrus/elbrus/Homework/project/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/mixin.js:18
        Object.assign(options, _.omit(source.options, ["hooks"]));          ^
    
    TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of function 'class ToDo extends Model {
        /**
         * Helper method for defining associations.
         * This method is not a ...<omitted>... }'
        at Function.assign (<anonymous>)
        at Function.hasMany (/home/ds/elbrus/elbrus/Homework/project/node_modules/sequelize/src/associations/mixin.js:27:12)
        at Function.associate (/home/ds/elbrus/elbrus/Homework/project/db/models/user.js:15:12)
```

```
          
    const {
      Model
    } = require('sequelize');
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
      class User extends Model {
        static associate({ Post, ToDo }) {
          this.hasMany(Post, ToDo, { foreignKey: 'authorId' });
        }
      }
      User.init({
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        email: DataTypes.STRING,
        password: DataTypes.STRING
      }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: 'User',
      });
      return User;
    };
```

```
        
    const {
      Model
    } = require('sequelize');
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
      class ToDo extends Model {
        static associate({ User }) {
          this.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'authorId', as: 'author' });      
        }
      }
      ToDo.init({
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        status: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        authorId: DataTypes.INTEGER
      }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: 'ToDo',
      });
      return ToDo;
    };
```

```
        
    /** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
    module.exports = {
      async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        await queryInterface.createTable('ToDos', {
          id: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
          },
          name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
          },
          status: {
            type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
          },
          authorId: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            references: {
              model: 'Users',
              key: 'id',
            },
            onDelete: 'CASCADE',
            allowNull: false,
          },
          createdAt: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DATE
          },
          updatedAt: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DATE
          }
        });
      },
      async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        await queryInterface.dropTable('ToDos');
      }
    };
```

```
       
   /** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
   module.exports = {
     async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
       await queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
         id: {
           allowNull: false,
           autoIncrement: true,
           primaryKey: true,
           type: Sequelize.INTEGER
         },
         name: {
           type: Sequelize.STRING
         },
         email: {
           type: Sequelize.STRING,
           unique: true,
         },
         password: {
           type: Sequelize.STRING
         },
         createdAt: {
           allowNull: false,
           type: Sequelize.DATE
         },
         updatedAt: {
           allowNull: false,
           type: Sequelize.DATE
         }
       });
     },
     async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
       await queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
     }
   };
```